# Itaerating through one mysql table and updating another where matches are found

Tags: mysql, loops

I've got a problem with updating an online database with offline accounts. Don't ask... it's a Charlie-Foxtrot if you get my drift but I have to find a solution none-the-less.

I need to have the following logic happen and it's far beyond my skill-set.  There is roughly 28,000 records in the import table and 2,400 in the members and member_data tables - if that helps at all.  I'm hoping a kind soul with strong kung-fu with this stuff can help me out.

The tables:

```
members
    id
    group_id
member_data
    id
    account
    phone
    modified
import
    account
    phone
```

The desired logic:

```
Loop through each record in import table and search for match between import.account and member_data.account.

If Match:
    Update members.group_id to '5'.
    Update member_data.modified to '1'.

If No Match:
    Search for match between import.phone and member_data.phone.
        If Match:
            Update member_data.account with import.account of the matched record.
            Update members.group_id to '5'.
            Update member_data.modified to '1'.
```

Answer (score 0):

As a start you can look into this link in the "Other Non Standard Implementations" section:

[Merge (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29)

If I am correctly translating my TSQL experience over to MySQL's flavor then you are going to need what's called an INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement.  Founder here:

[MySQL Documentation for INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

What this is doing is essentialy inserting records until a key violation occurs.  In your case account number makes a record unique.  When it finds a key violation (a matching record) you can then specify what you want to happen through an update statement.

I hope this helps you down the road a bit.